# netstream.buffer.empty red5 , Flash Player hangs

Tags: flash, red5, flash-media-server

I'm developping a Flex Application to be able to live stream video by red5.

When I am using the latest flashplayer(11.4), the flash player will become stutter and hang sometimes .Surprisingly, that doesn't occur when I am using fms(flash media server). Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What red5 version are you using? It might be worth to update to latest revision and build your own copy and try with that.